# RequestParam = false doesnt return everything

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi guys new to spring and was wondering why this does work like I though it would. So I have a project model which has a name(a string) and a user(a user object). So I store it mysql and want to retrieve a project base on those two fields and i want to display the project on page which I did already(but only base on user). So add a new thing where I'm using a search bar for input for name. So when the page first load, there isn't any input so it should just retrieve all projects base of user. So I made name (required = false). However, it doesn't show all the projects only base on user(Nothing shows). It only something shows when I enter like a name into search bar.

```
<form class="form-inline mt-5 my-lg-0" action="/myWork">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Search Project" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary"/></form>

public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Integer> {

@Override
List<Project> findAll();

public List<Project> findByUser(User user);

public List<Project>findByUserAndName(User user,String name);

public List<Project> findByType(String type);
```

}

```
    //Get a project base on user and project name
public List<Project> getProjectByUserandName(Authentication authentication,String name) {
    User user = authenticationService.getPrincipal(authentication);
    return projectRepo.findByUserAndName(user,name);
```

}

```
 @GetMapping("/myWork")
public ModelAndView showUserProject(Authentication authentication, @RequestParam(required = false) String name) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<Project>();
    try {


        projects = projectService.getProjectByUserandName(authentication,name);
        System.out.println(projects);
        Collections.sort(projects, new customComparator());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    modelAndView.addObject("projects", projects);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: Because that is what you are returning. You are always executing the same query `userAndName` only with a name of `null` ... You should execute another method if `name` is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Handle Empty case of name in `getProjectByUserandName`.

Instead of

```java
return projectRepo.findByUserAndName(user,name);
```

Use this :

```java
if(StringUtils.isEmpty(name))
 return projectRepo.findByUser(user);
else 
 return projectRepo.findByUserAndName(user,name);
```